# Service Fabric ApplicationManifest parameterized certificaterefs?

Tags: ssl, azure-service-fabric

I have a solution with multiple SF services. Some of them use HTTPS endpoints, so I have these specs (details hidden or changed)

We are several developers, and we are using self-signed certificates for local deployment.

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Api_SslCertHash" DefaultValue="<my-thumbprint-here!>" />
</Parameters>
```

and

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="SomeAppPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <Policies>
      <EndpointBindingPolicy EndpointRef="ServiceEndpointHttps" CertificateRef="mycert" />
    </Policies>
</ServiceManifestImport>
```

and then

```
<Certificates>
  <EndpointCertificate X509FindValue="[Api_SslCertHash]" Name="mycert" />
</Certificates>
```

Now the problem is that we have this file checked in to Git, and since everyone has their own self-signed cert (Not: I don't know if this has to be, maybe we can share certs, by the question remains anyway) the thumbprint is different per developer.

My question is: Is it possible to have the thumbprint in an environment-variable, or get it from another source instead of changing it in the ApplicationManifest. I realise that it could be hard in a cluster environment, but maybe when deploying locally?

I have a similar requirement for ServiceManifest, where I would like to have different port numbers. I know I can override it in Local.1Node.xml but it would be nice to be able to pick it up externally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you cant use a variable like you are doing in your last example, but that doesn't solve your multiple developer problem.

The correct way to handle this is to generate a certificate, check it into source control and make everyone else use the same certificate. In fact, if you set up a secure cluster in production, anyone who wants to be able to view the Explorer will need the same certificate installed on their machine in order to authenticate.

Comment: I would suggest you avoid adding certs to source control and use KeyVault or direct upload to your environment instead. Then you add the thumbprint to source control.

For local development, point to a path and keep the private certs out of source control but make sure each dev have a cert.